# How to style logo of my website in right way?

Tags: html, css

I have created the logo of my website as text, but the first part of my logo "hello" needs other styling than the second part "Kitty"

requirements:

- both words have to be italic, so I created a h1 class "logo-text" DONE
- the seconds word "Kitty" needs to be bold NOT DONE

  ```
  <h1 class="logo-text">

    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" rel="home">hello

       <span class="logo-text-kitty>"Kitty</span>
    </a>
  </h1>
  ```

What is the right way to make "Kitty" bold? Using a span?

Comment: Is that entire php stuff relevant to your question?

Comment: @Jongware We left presentational markup like `<center>` and `<font>` in the dust years ago. HTML should describe content, not appearance. The fact that `strong` makes something bold by default is not enough reason to use it whenever you want bold text. It's nit-picky, but I believe this is the essence of the question.

Comment: the css is not important for me, its just about the html semantic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<style>
.bold-class{
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<h1 class="logo-text"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' );?>" rel="home"><span class="bold-class">helloKitty</span></a></h1>
```

Comment: I dislike everything about this answer. You don't need to call a class "-class", since we already know it's a class. You don't need to name things as 'bold', as that's not really describing the data (that's the entire reason <b> as defined as 'bold' was redefined in later html standards), and you're continuing to use a <span> when a <strong> would make a lot more sense.

Comment: oh and as pointed out on my other answer, <b> might be better than <strong>. Not the most important point, as <span> is the least of the offences in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can style each word separately by giving it a class

### HTML

```
<h1 class="logo-text">
    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" rel="home">
        <span class="logo-first-word">hello</span>
        <span class="logo-second-word">Kitty</span>
    </a>
</h1>
```

### CSS

```
.logo-first-word{
    //some CSS code
}

.logo-second-word{
    font-weight:bold;
    //some CSS code
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but Flamur was 4 minutes faster so :)

Comment: Inline-styling like your first answer is very bad form. HTML describes your content, and CSS describes the style. There's an occasional use for style elements, generally if it's rendered content (e.g. including a background-image from your PHP), but in this cases you're directly splitting the same styling across html and css. Your second approach, however, is sound.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tag that best describes the content. In this case, `<strong>`. Alternatively, `<b>` would be a better choice if 'kitty' isn't really more important than 'hello', simple meant to be formatted different.

Comment: But <strong> doesnt mean "bold" right??? Do I have to style the strong as bold then...?

Comment: I would prefer `<b>` over `<strong>` in a logo.  `<strong>` indicates a strong emphasis, and might not be appropriate here.

Comment: @Engin You don't have to style `<strong>` to make it appear bold, that's the default styling.

Comment: Unless specifically re-styled, `<strong>` displays as bold text. The same goes for `<b>`.

Comment: `strong` is for emphasis. Use `b` (maybe) or `span` (safe bet).

Comment: It's not for emphasis - that's <em>, <strong> means "strong importance", though I do agree <b> makes the most sense if 'kitty' isn't considered more 'important', and on closer inspection that's likely the case.